# bash Sort uniq list of numbers and strings

Tags: string, list, sorting, awk, numbers

I would like to sort and merge list in the following format

```
123 ABC
  1 ABC
345 BGF
  3 BGF
```

to

```
124 ABC
348 BGF
```

Thank you.

In bash thank you

Comment: Welcome to SO, please show your coding efforts.

Comment: @Cyrus oh sorry first time using stackoverflow and I am beginner in bash. I have been using sort -k2,2 -k1,1nr | uniq -c

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using awk you can do this:

```
awk '{a[$2]+=$1} END{for (i in a) print a[i], i}' file

124 ABC
348 BGF
```